# select row when triggering commandbutton

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

I have a datatable and in one of the columns there is a downloadbutton that is suppposed to start a download for whatever is in that row. How do you automatically select the row where the download button is clicked?

```
<p:column style="width:150px">
   <p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s">
       <p:fileDownload value="#{dtEditView.file}" />
   </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

It seems to be trivial, but i just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

there is not enough code to repair but i think u have some p:dataTable

```
<p:dataTable var="row" value="#{bean.listOfElementsToFillTable}">
   <p:column style="width:150px">
       <p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s">
          <p:fileDownload value="#{bean.getFile(row)}" />
       </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

row can be entity or any object

bean method:

```
public void getFile(Row row) {
    try {
        byte[] rowFile = somehowGetFile();
        Faces.sendFile(rowFile, "fileName" + ".pdf", false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is: row is null, when a row is not selected. I want to select the row automatically, when the according downloadbutton in the row is being pressed.